# MySQL error 0: Retrieval of the RSA public key is not enabled for insecure connections

Tags: mysql, windows-installer, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I need to set up MySQL database in my computer. I downloaded the Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/).

I run the installer. At the final stage, the installer reach `Apply configuration` stage.
[image]

But it stops at `Starting Server`. The log says:

```
    MySQL error 0: Retrieval of the RSA public key is not enabled for insecure connections. Failed to connect to MySQL Server 8.0.11 after 10 attempts. Ended configuration step: Starting Server
```

I already entered a root and added a user and created a password for them. The passwords had yellow warning, meaning that they are not strong, but also not weak. The wizard accepted them so I proceeded.

Can you please help me identify the source of the problem and how to solve it?

**EDIT:**
I am using Windows 10. The server is my localhost.

Comment: Unsure about this particular scenario, but we encountered the same error message with the .NET Connector. It came down to the MySQL user we were using - we changed the default authentication plugin (`default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password` in my.ini) and then, importantly, recreated the user account. Alternatively the user account can be [specifically created with](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html) the `mysql_native_password` plugin via `IDENTIFIED WITH` if you want to avoid changing the default.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after importing some new data into my DB.

Deleting and then recreating my MySql User worked for me.